# ArcGIS for INSPIRE - GetMap validation

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-10.4, inspire

I've set a InspireView service using ArcGIS for INSPIRE 10.4. The INSPIRE theme is Administrative Units.

That service has its metadata. The two layers of the service have their own dataset metadata.

If I test it with the INSPIRE validator, it can't perform a GetMap request. I have done the request by hand and it works perfectly, so I don't understando what is happening.

Anyone can help me?

This is the Capabilities of the service: http://www.araba.eus/arcgis/rest/services/Geograma/AU/MapServer/exts/InspireView/service?REQUEST=GetCapabilities&SERVICE=WMS

This is the validator URL: http://inspire-geoportal.ec.europa.eu/validator2/

This is the error: "The Get Map request "" was not successful ("Could not retrieve an HTTP resource at url: "null" (Invalid layer bounding box)")"

Comment: The validation​ is for metadata nothing to do with a GetMap request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the source data. I didn't project it correctly.

Answer (score 1):

The *INSPIRE Geoportal Metadata Validator* validates metadata.  A WMS GetMap request is not a metadata request, and therefore it is correct that if you paste a GetMap request into the text field provided by the form (http://inspire-geoportal.ec.europa.eu/validator2/), you will get an error.

You may paste the **OGC Service Endpoint** for your WMS service as:

> http://www.araba.eus/arcgis/rest/services/Geograma/AU/MapServer/exts/InspireView/service?

which gives the following report:

http://inspire-geoportal.ec.europa.eu/resources/sandbox/INSPIRE-d031ae71-1dcc-11e7-a02d-52540023a883_20170410-110516/

and you can post the **GetRecordById GET Request** for your service as:

> http://www.araba.eus/geonetwork/srv/spa/csw?SERVICE=CSW&VERSION=2.0.2&REQUEST=GetRecordById&ID=83bfeeac-b3fb-4f36-b3da-4c34711e1388&ElementSetName=full&outputSchema=csw:IsoRecord

which gives me the following report:

http://inspire-geoportal.ec.europa.eu/resources/sandbox/INSPIRE-eda7728e-1dcb-11e7-a02d-52540023a883_20170410-105856/

and you can post the **OGC Service Endpoint** for your CSW service as:

> http://www.araba.eus/geonetwork/srv/spa/csw?

The report may take some time to come back depending on the number of metadata records you have in the catalogue...